# Are plasma holograms really 3D

Tags: hologram

After reading [this article](https://gizmodo.com/you-can-feel-these-plasma-holograms-made-with-femtoseco-1715036802) and watching the video attached in it, I wondered if a plasma hologram is really as three dimensional as they say. I would say the hologram is **only**  three dimensional if you can walk around it, and see the image from different angles as you walk. But is this really the case when walking around a plasma hologram, as it seems more like a 2D image projected mid-air. Next to that, looking to the setup shown in the video, I would say it is not even possible creating a '3D plasma hologram' using that setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if the hologram was two-dimensional, you could still walk around it. If you consider a piece of paper to be nearly two-dimensional, it's not like you can't walk around it. Defining something to be 3D with your definition would be misguided.

If you are asking whether the hologram can *itself* have depth (i.e projecting a sphere), I see no reason as to why it cannot. Second paragraph http://gizmodo.com/new-laser-projector-makes-3d-images-that-hang-in-mid-ai-1652174565 explains how this process works. It doesn't look like there exists any limitations to focusing pulses in an arrangement that produces 3D objects.

Comment: No the question was not in that sense if you could walk around it, but if the image would be 3D if you walk around it. I was asking if the hologram itself has depth. Thanks for the answer.